# chaco to matplotlib conversion

Tags: python, matplotlib, tornado, chaco

Is it possible to convert chaco code to equivalent matplotlib code?

For example I would like to convert [this](https://github.com/enthought/chaco/blob/master/examples/demo/tornado.py) chaco code to equivalent matplotlib code. I am new dealing with matplot library. So any kind of help is highly appreciated.

**Code Snippet**

```
""" Tornado plot example from Brennan Williams """
from enable.api import Component, ComponentEditor
from traits.api import HasTraits, Instance
from traitsui.api import Item, View

# Chaco imports
from chaco.api import ArrayDataSource, BarPlot, DataRange1D, LabelAxis, \
                  LinearMapper, OverlayPlotContainer, PlotAxis
from chaco.example_support import COLOR_PALETTE

class PlotExample(HasTraits):
    plot = Instance(Component)

    traits_view = View(Item('plot', editor=ComponentEditor(), show_label=False),
                resizable=True, title="Tornado Plot",
                width=800, height=600
                )

    def _plot_default(self):
        container = OverlayPlotContainer(bgcolor = "white")
        plots = self._make_curves()
        for plot in plots:
        plot.padding = 60
        container.add(plot)

        bottom_axis = PlotAxis(plot, orientation='bottom')

        label_list=['var a', 'var b', 'var c', 'var d', 'var e', 'var f',
                'var g', 'var h', 'var i']
        vertical_axis = LabelAxis(plot, orientation='left',
                            title='Categories',
                            positions = range(1, 10),
                            labels=label_list)
        vertical2_axis = LabelAxis(plot, orientation='right',
                               positions = range(1, 10),
                               labels=label_list)

        plot.underlays.append(vertical_axis)
        plot.underlays.append(vertical2_axis)
        plot.underlays.append(bottom_axis)

        return container

    def _get_points(self):
        index = linspace(pi/4, 3*pi/2, 9)
        data = sin(index) + 2
        return (range(1, 10), data)

    def _make_curves(self):
        (index_points, value_points) = self._get_points()
        size = len(index_points)

        middle_value=2500000.0
        mid_values=middle_value*ones(size)
        low_values=mid_values-10000.0*value_points
        high_values=mid_values+20000.0*value_points

        idx = ArrayDataSource(index_points)
        vals = ArrayDataSource(low_values, sort_order="none")

        idx2 = ArrayDataSource(index_points)
        vals2 = ArrayDataSource(high_values, sort_order="none")

        starting_vals = ArrayDataSource(mid_values, sort_order="none")

        # Create the index range
        index_range = DataRange1D(idx, low=0.5, high=9.5)
        index_mapper = LinearMapper(range=index_range)

        # Create the value range
        value_range = DataRange1D(vals, vals2, low_setting='auto',
                              high_setting='auto', tight_bounds=False)
        value_mapper = LinearMapper(range=value_range,tight_bounds=False)

        # Create the plot
        plot1 = BarPlot(index=idx, value=vals,
                    value_mapper=value_mapper,
                    index_mapper=index_mapper,
                    starting_value=starting_vals,
                    line_color='black',
                    orientation='v',
                    fill_color=tuple(COLOR_PALETTE[6]),
                    bar_width=0.8, antialias=False)

        plot2 = BarPlot(index=idx2, value=vals2,
                    value_mapper=value_mapper,
                    index_mapper=index_mapper,
                    starting_value=starting_vals,
                    line_color='black',
                    orientation='v',
                    fill_color=tuple(COLOR_PALETTE[1]),
                    bar_width=0.8, antialias=False)

        return [plot1, plot2]


demo = PlotExample()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo.configure_traits()
```

I want to generate a tornado diagram like the following.

[image: tornado diagram]

Comment: Please paste a code snippet instead of a link.  That said, I don't think the apis line up well enough to do a drop-in replacement and I don't know of any automated methods, but you can certainly make almost any graph using either library.

Comment: @tcaswell any example of tornado diagram(image i mentioned) in matplotlib is highly appreciated. btw code snippet is added to the question.

Comment: That is just `hbar` http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/barchart_demo2.html.  Have you tried to write any code using `matplotlib`?

Comment: @tcaswell , I have written codes using matplotlib and generated histogram and violin plot. but stucked into the tornado diagram.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.  People will gladly help you with fixing your code, but are much less willing to wholesale write code for you.

Comment: @tcaswell , I am not asking for any readymade wholesale code. any similar example of the above example in matplotlib is what my interest on. I have already generated tornado diagram in matplotlib, but couldn't produce the way i wanted. its in chaco library. thats what i asked help/suggestion, how to produce something similar in matplotlib.

Comment: @francescoMontesano, Thanks, but i have seen it way earlier, but i am looking for examples similar to the above image, so that i can understand it, and generate one based on my own criteria.

Answer (score 3):

In the matplotlib mailing list there is a year old thread about tornado diagrams. There are two different examples and a couple of links to a gallery with a tornado and corresponding source.
You can find the thread [here](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/tornado-chart-td26614.html)